# If Condition --- missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to run an "if" and "else if" condition to create a new variable based off values of two existing variables. Here is a sample output of the two existing variables I am writing my condition on.

Here is the dput to reproduce the two variables:

```
structure(list(C = c(NA, NA, "Standard", "Standard", NA, "Micro", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Nursery", "Standard", NA, "Micro", "Micro", 
NA, NA, NA, "Standard", "Standard"), P = c(NA, NA, "Standard", 
"Standard", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Standard", "Standard", 
"Micro", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Standard")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and here is the if and else if statement I am using:

```
if (DF$C=="Standard" | DF$P=="Standard") {
  mutate("Type" = "Standard")
} else if (DF$C=="Micro" | DF$P=="Micro") {
  mutate("Type" = "Micro")
} else if (DF$C=="Nursery" | DF$P=="Nursery") {
  mutate("Type" = "Nursery")
  } else {
    mutate("Type" = "Other")
  }
```

What I want is a new variable called "Type" with either values of "Standard", "Micro", "Nursery" or "Other", but I get this error message instead:

```
Error in if (Site.Details.TEST$C == "Standard" | Site.Details.TEST$P ==  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In if (Site.Details.TEST$C == "Standard" | Site.Details.TEST$P ==  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: I think that dplyr's `case_when()` is the way to go in this case, have a look at its documentation

Comment: In base R, you should replace the `if` and `else` statements with the vectorized `ifelse`. `if` expects a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` value and you are feeding it a vector of length larger than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something vectorized like this in `dplyr` will do the trick. Basically you are looking to see if one of three matches ("Standard", "Micro", or "Nursery") are met in either field `C` or `P`. If this is met, take that matched value. If neither column matches, then code as "Other".

This works assuming `C` and `P` cannot be different things. If they are, preference is given to `C`.

```
library(dplyr)

check_types <- c("Standard", "Micro", "Nursery")

DF %>%
  mutate(Type = if_else(C %in% check_types | P %in% check_types, if_else(is.na(C), P, C), "Other"))

   C        P        Type    
   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
 1 NA       NA       Other   
 2 NA       NA       Other   
 3 Standard Standard Standard
 4 Standard Standard Standard
 5 NA       NA       Other
```

The `if_else(condition, true, false)` statement looks for a vectorized condition, and then either a single value for `true` and `false`, or a vectored value of the same length as the condition. In this case:

**condition:**

```
C %in% check_types | P %in% check_types
```

This is a vector equal in length the number of rows in the data frame. Each position in the vector is based on `dplyr` evaluating at that respective row.

The value will be `TRUE` if `C` is one of the options in `check_types` or if `P` is one of the options in `check_types`. Otherwise it will be `FALSE`

**true:**

```
if_else(is.na(C), P, C)
```

If the statement is evaluated to `TRUE`, then now check to see which value to take. If (again, at that given vector spot, or row) `C` is `NA`, then take `P`. Otherwise, take `C`.

**false:**

```
"Other"
```

If the statement evaluated to `FALSE`, then take the value to be "Other".

Comment: This works, but are you able to explain how the nested if_else is working here? I am trying to understand how it is being processed?

Comment: Hopefully that is a bit more clear. It takes a bit of practice to figure out what `dplyr` is looking for exactly. The entire thing is vectorized.

Comment: This is fantastic. I understand it now. Thanks Adam!

Answer (score 0):

This is almost the same as previous answer:

```
> df %>% mutate(Type=case_when(C==P ~ C, 
          is.na(C) & is.na(P) ~ "Other", !is.na(C) ~ C, !is.na(P) ~ P))
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   C        P        Type    
   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
 1 NA       NA       Other   
 2 NA       NA       Other   
 3 Standard Standard Standard
 4 Standard Standard Standard
 5 NA       NA       Other   
 6 Micro    NA       Micro   
 7 NA       NA       Other   
 8 NA       NA       Other   
 9 NA       NA       Other   
10 NA       NA       Other   
11 Nursery  NA       Nursery 
12 Standard Standard Standard
13 NA       Standard Standard      
14 Micro    Micro    Micro   
15 Micro    NA       Micro   
16 NA       NA       Other   
17 NA       NA       Other   
18 NA       NA       Other   
19 Standard NA       Standard
20 Standard Standard Standard
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `ifelse` in standard R, since you essentially just want to populated the Type field when both P and C fields match and are not NA.

```
DF$Type <- ifelse( (is.na(DF$P) | is.na(DF$C)) | (DF$P != DF$C), 'Other', DF$C)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. This does't work though because I want the condition to populate the "Type" field as long as one of the three words "Standard", "Micro" or "Nursery" exist in either of the two existing varialbes "C" and "P". In your code, if one of the variables has an "NA" then it will lable the type as "Other"